# Condensing data frame with same names and different values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that I am trying to condense. There are multiple value os `X` with the same names but with different `Y` values associated with them:

```
  X Y
1 a 1
2 b 3
3 a 2
4 c 4
5 b 7
```

I want to condense the data frame so there are no duplicate names in `X`, like below:

```
  X Y
1 a 3
2 b 10
3 c 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>%
group_by(x) %>%
summarise(y = sum(y))
```